# What is the story of sage Pulaha?

Tags: rishi, vishnu-purana

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp041.htm#page_49)  I have read something 
but I didn't find a better reference related to **Sage Pulaha**,
I only know that he married a daughter of **Daksha** named **Kshamā** (Patience), by whom he had three sons. 
[image: SaptRishis]

Comment: Hi Eshan, it will be great if you can link the photograph back to the actual content. I am the original photographer for this photo. here is the actual link to the photo. https://flic.kr/p/ak2kbr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it

## PULAHA

Pulaha is named among the principal Saptarishis, or those most often listed from the first Manvantara: Bhrigu, Angiras, Marici, Atri, Vasistha, Pulastya, Pulaha and Kratu. Pulaha was manas-putra of Prajapati as mentioned  [Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hmvp/hmvp38.htm)
According to Vishnu Purana He was born from the navel of Lord Brahma. [Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp041.htm)

According to Vishnu Purana The wife of Pulaha was Kshama.

[Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp045.htm)

> Kshamá, the wife of the patriarch Pulaha, was the mother of three sons, Karmasa, Arvarívat, and Sahishńu

According to Srimad Bhagwatam an another wife of Brahmarishi Pulaha was **GATI**

[Source](http://vanisource.org/wiki/SB_4.1.38?terms=all%20her%20sons%20were%20as%20good%20as%20he&first=SB%204.1.38,%20Translation%20and%20Purport:%20Gati,%20the%20wife%20of%20the&last=husband,%20and%20all%20her%20sons%20were%20as%20good%20as%20he.?terms=all%20her%20sons%20were%20as%20good%20as%20he&first=SB%204.1.38,%20Translation%20and%20Purport:%20Gati,%20the%20wife%20of%20the&last=husband,%20and%20all%20her%20sons%20were%20as%20good%20as%20he.)

> pulahasya gatir bhāryā
>
> trīn asūta satī sutān
>
> karmaśreṣṭhaṁ varīyāṁsaṁ
>
> sahiṣṇuṁ ca mahā-mate

**Translation**

Gati,( daughter of Kardama Muni) the wife of the sage Pulaha, gave birth to three sons, named Karmaśreṣṭha, Varīyān and Sahiṣṇu, and all of them were great sages.

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk10ch09.htm) is Something mentioned in Devi Bhagwatam related with sage pulaha.